# opengl glDrawElements Issues

Tags: c, opengl, drawing

Well, Pretty sure the problem is fairly simple, but i'm not seeing the issues and debugger isn't helping me. Anyway, I'm trying to draw a plane, and all i get is black. I'm honestly not sure if it drawing it, but is too small to be seen.

```
int index[][3] = {{0,1,4}, {0,3,4}, {1,2,5}, {1,4,5}};
double VertexA[][3] = {{0.0 , 0.0 , -.0415}, {0.5, 0.0, .6543}, {1.0,0,-.0415},
                       {0.0, 0.5, .093}, {0.5, 0.5, -.070}, {1.0, 0.5 , .093},
                       {0.0,1.0, -.0415}, {0.5, 1.0, .6543}, {1.0,1.0,-.0415}}

 void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 24, VertexA);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, index);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glutSwapBuffers();
 }
 void reshape(int w, int h) {
    if (w <= h) {
      glViewport(0,(h-w)/2, w,w);
    }
    else {
      glViewport((w-h)/2,0,h,h);
    }
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(30.0, w/h, 10.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

 }
```

This is the snippet of my code modified with a defined VertexA/Index array. I'm pretty sure the index/vertexArray was obtain correctly, it the part of drawing it is where i get the issues. I'm guessing I'm misusing glDrawElement or gluPerspective. Honestly, I'm not sure. Do I need to have a ColorArray?  It should be white if i do not define a color in the first place right? Any questions or you want more of a the snippet ask away, but i have a feeling the issues is within the snippet.

Comment: Aside: my compiler gives a syntax error when trying to initialise `double` with `.0.5` (your line 3).

Comment: Fix it, it was a typo, I didn't want to post the whole code where i get the VertexA/Index data

Answer (score 3):

Your object is totally out of the viewing frustum. You are using an identity matrix as ModelView, and `gluPrespective` with `near=10` and `far=100` as Projection. As a result, the view volume will be  from z=-10 to z=-100, while your objects lie at z=-0.1 to z=0.1, so they are clipped by the near plane.

Answer (score 2):

The function `gluPerspective` needs a floating point argument for `aspect`. Your line is

```
gluPerspective(30.0, w/h, 10.0, 100.0);
```

but the calculation `w/h` is an integer division. I suggest that you use `(double)w / h` or perhaps `(GLdouble)w / h`.

Comment: Wouldn't the int be forced to double anyway?  Well, I checked and tested. Didn't seem to help. Does the znear/zfar look fine? I don't think that is the issues, but never quite sure how to determine the ideal one to use.

Comment: Sorry it did not help. The division is done without regard to the target type: expressions are evaluated according to the types they contain, then converted to the target type, if necessary.